# Spoofing the user agent of an embedded Safari browser on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, safari, user-agent, spoofing

Is there any way to spoof the user agent on Safari on the iPhone?

So for example, you would create an application on the iPhone that has the embedded Safari browser, however any website the user visits with this browser wouldn't know you were on Safari on the iPhone, it would think you are on something like Safari on a PC, or even IE/FireFox.

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to do this?

Comment: Because you want to see the full version of a web site instead of the crippled mobile version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes I think you could change this.  It would require a bit of a work around to get it working.

1. You would need to manually manage all requests. By making your own data requests.
   In this data request you can add a HTTPheader for User-Agent which will override the default headers.

   NSMutableURLRequest* urlRequest = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:requestURL] autorelease];

   ```
   [urlRequest setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
   [urlRequest setHTTPBody: [nvpString  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [urlRequest addValue:@"Your+User+Agent+String" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
   receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] retain];
   [receivedData setLength:0];

   [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest: urlRequest delegate: self];
   ```
2. If you embed the Safari Web Browser in your app you can subscribe to its delegate methods. One of them will notify your application that safari would like to load a URL, this is where you catch this load and get the data your self.

   ```
   - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
   ```

   now you put your code in here to do the data load.
3. Once the data has loaded. Give it the data string back to the webView. I have set "baseURL:nil" but you might have to correctly set this to maybe the correct domain for this app.

   [webView loadHTMLString:newString baseURL:nil]

Comment: I'd like to confirm that this works.  Inside the webView delegate shouldStartLoad method, I used the first three lines of suggestion 1.  I set the HTTP body to nil, because I don't know what the nvpString thing was.  Didn't need the receivedData thing.